# R and snow on amazon EC2 using starcluster

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run analysis in parrallel in R on an AWS EC2 cluster. I am using
starcluster to setup and manage the EC2 cluster, and am trying to use `snow` and
`foreach` in R. To start off, I have 2 nodes in the cluster, 1 master and 1 
worker.

```
starcluster start mycluster 
starcluster listinstances

-----------------------------------------
mycluster (security group: @sc-mycluster)
-----------------------------------------
....
Cluster nodes:
     master running i-xxxxxxxxx masterIP.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    node001 running i-xxxxxxxxx node001IP.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Total nodes: 2

starcluster sshmaster mycluster
```

I then start R and load the `snow` package and try to create a cluster 
object.

```
R
library("snow")

cl = makeCluster(c("masterIP.compute-1.amazonaws.com", "node001IP.compute-1.amazonaws.com"), type = "SOCK")
```

This, however, gives me the following error message:

```
The authenticity of host 'masterIP.compute-1.amazonaws.com (xx.xxx.xx.xx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'masterIP.compute-1.amazonaws.com,xx.xxx.xx.xx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

So I tried copying my ssh key (`keyname.rsa` to be specific) to the .ssh file 
on EC2 and trying again. That still didn't work; I received the same 
`Permission denied (publickey).` error. It was my thought that starcluster
handled the setup of ssh and communication between nodes, so I'm a little
confused as to why I'm not able to set this up. I also tried to just add node001, so `cl = makeCluster(c("node001IP.compute-1.amazonaws.com"), type = "SOCK")`, but the same error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, after much tinkering, that all that was needed was an update to R version 2.15. The command `cl = makeCluster(c("masterIP.compute-1.amazonaws.com", "node001IP.compute-1.amazonaws.com"), type = "SOCK")` worked perfectly after that.